# django allauth signup UnicodeDecodeError in domain variable

Tags: django, email, django-allauth

I was trying to add django-allauth to my Django web app and I am getting an error when trying to sign up. The error happens when sending the email. The domain variable at that point is getting my computer's name (I am working in locahost) that has a non-ascii character. The error is being raised in the core.mail module of Django. How could I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup/

Django Version: 1.8.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django_extensions',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'core',
 'authentication',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount')
Installed Middleware:
(u'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  169.         return super(SignupView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  66.                                             **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  147.                                                           **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in post
  82.             response = self.form_valid(form)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in form_valid
  185.                                self.get_success_url())
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py" in complete_signup
  157.                          signal_kwargs=signal_kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py" in perform_login
  114.             send_email_confirmation(request, user, signup=signup)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py" in send_email_confirmation
  286.                                                     signup=signup)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/models.py" in send_confirmation
  60.         confirmation.send(request, signup=signup)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/models.py" in send
  137.                                 ctx)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py" in send_mail
  101.         msg.send()
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  304.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/console.py" in send_messages
  36.                     self.write_message(message)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/console.py" in write_message
  18.         msg = message.message()
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in message
  284.             msg['Message-ID'] = make_msgid(domain=DNS_NAME)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in make_msgid
  64.     msgid = '<%s.%s.%s%s@%s>' % (utcdate, pid, randint, idstring, domain)

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /accounts/signup/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question. This is an existing issue with python ([Issue 9377](http://bugs.python.org/issue9377)). Basically, it is necessary to change your computer's name to something without non-ASCII characters. My recommendation is to do it through the terminal with the next command: sudo scutil --set HostName [NewHostNameHere]. Probably will also be required restarting the computer.